# Embedded YouTube video views on iOS app are not counted

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I added embedded Youtube video to my iOS app. It's work, but not counted as view counts!
I couldn't find its access on YouTube studio.
The video is YouTube Live Stream.
**Doesn't playing via API consider as right view counts?**
I feel the criteria is blackbox.

Selected library is below:

[YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView](https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView)

My code is below:

```swift
    private let youtubePlayer = WKYTPlayerView()

    private func loadInline() {
        youtubePlayer.load(withVideoId: videoID,
                           playerVars: ["playsinline": 1, "controls": 1])
    }
    
    func startInline() {
        youtubePlayer.playVideo()
    }
```

I could find my access from YouTube App.
Perhaps mobile access via API is not counted, but official YouTube app is counted.
I cannot find related documents.

Comment: Welcome to SO! So, what exactly is your question? Why it's not counted? If there is a way to get it counted?

Comment: Oh thanks. I just explained the issue, not questioned. I want to know the criteria of YouTube view counts. I will edit my question as an obvious question.

Comment: @st43 only YouTube knows and is not available at public.

Comment: @st43 Hi, 
Only manually initiated playback will be counted. 
from YT Docs
"Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player."
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read YouTube Documents in Japanese, but its translation is somehow misunderstood. The comments on the question helped me understand that.

Clearly YouTube declares they count only play via a native play button.
It means playback via API call is ignored.
(I guess it means user tap action would be counted.
A play button on my app is not "native")

> Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

[Playback controls and player settings](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)